# Show events in fullcalendar JSON

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

I'm learning to use Bootstrap's fullCalendar and I've been looking for a solution with no success. My code is the following:

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, 
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, 
      events: {
        url: 'getEventos/',
        error: function() {
          alert(1);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function getEventos(){
    $eventos = Eventooooo::find(1);
    $evento = ['title' => $eventos->evento,
               'start' => $eventos->fechaEvento,
               'end'   => $eventos->fechaEvento,
    ];
    return response()->json($evento);
}
```

I'm sending JSON with indexes the way *calendar* hopes to receive it, just to send *response* to *event* and it brings the data I need correctly. With this code I'm using doesn't show any error nor the event in the calendar. 
I followed a tutorial that the person had the same problem, so this person did the following:

**Tutorial code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('getEventos/', function(response, state){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
          },
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: $.parseJSON(response),
        });
    });     
});
```

This generates an error and it didn't work in my code. I would like to know if somebody has had the same problem and how I can solve it. Thanks.

Comment: "Bootstrap's fullCalendar"??? https://fullcalendar.io/ is a completely indepdent piece of software made by a single developer (not me!), nothing to do with Bootstrap. It doesn't even depend on Bootstrap.

Comment: Anyway, the tutorial version has got the architecture the wrong way round. You don't need to wait for your events to download in order to display the calendar. You can just do `events: "getEventos"` directly, without the ajax wrapper. You also need to get your method to accept "start" and "end" parameters to filter the events returned to just those needed by the current view. Then, fullCalendar will call the ajax again when the view / date range changes and download the next set of appropriate events. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ for how to set it up.

Comment: That way, you always get the latest version of your events from the server, and, once your app is mature and you have hundreds/thousands of events in there, you don't slow down the initial setup by waiting for them all to download at once (especially when probably 99% of them will never been seen by the user - it'll be rare that they look at an event from many years previously!). Your first version should work fine. If it doesn't, check the network tab in your browser to see what is actually being returned by your server in the response body, and that it matches what you expect.